# Delete Query with Conditions from Multiple Tables: Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records from the "AC_DETAIL" Table that meet a certain criteria in the "AC_PROPERTY" Table; however, when I run the query I get the error "Could not delete from specified tables." I am using MS Access 2010 and fairly new to it. Anyone have an idea why this is wrong and how it can be fixed to work?

```
DELETE 

AC_DETAIL.*

FROM AC_PROPERTY 
INNER JOIN AC_DETAIL 
 ON (AC_PROPERTY.YEAR = AC_DETAIL.YEAR) 
 AND (AC_PROPERTY.NUM = AC_DETAIL.NUM)

WHERE (((AC_PROPERTY.YEAR)="2015") 
 AND ((AC_PROPERTY.REGION)="CT") 
 AND ((AC_DETAIL.SOURCE)="BPF") 
 AND ((AC_DETAIL.SCENARIO)="PRICES") 
 AND ((AC_PROPERTY.STATUS)="NO-PROD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed the `DELETE` and `SELECT` syntaxes, you can't explicitly join tables in a `DELETE` statement.
With MS Access 2000 I think you could use a workaround like that (I can't test it right now, so I'm not sure it's going to work):

```
DELETE AC_DETAIL.* FROM AC_DETAIL WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM AC_PROPERTY WHERE
        AC_PROPERTY.YEAR    = AC_DETAIL.YEAR    AND
        AC_PROPERTY.NUM     = AC_DETAIL.NUM     AND
        AC_PROPERTY.YEAR    = "2015"            AND 
        AC_PROPERTY.REGION  = "CT"              AND 
        AC_DETAIL.SOURCE    = "BPF"             AND 
        AC_DETAIL.SCENARIO  = "PRICES"          AND 
        AC_PROPERTY.STATUS  = "NO-PROD"
);
```

**EDIT :** If you have a field `NUM` as primary key in `AC_DETAIL` table then something like that should work:

```
DELETE FROM AC_DETAIL WHERE NUM IN (
    SELECT AC_DETAIL.NUM 
    FROM AC_DETAIL
    INNER JOIN AC_PROPERTY ON (AC_PROPERTY.YEAR = AC_DETAIL.YEAR) AND (AC_PROPERTY.NUM = AC_DETAIL.NUM) 
    WHERE (((AC_PROPERTY.YEAR)="2015") 
         AND ((AC_PROPERTY.REGION)="CT") 
         AND ((AC_DETAIL.SOURCE)="BPF") 
         AND ((AC_DETAIL.SCENARIO)="PRICES") 
         AND ((AC_PROPERTY.STATUS)="NO-PROD"));
    );
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "AggregateType is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."

Comment: I'm sorry I can't test it right now. A different **and much better** approach would be using `WHERE [primary_key] IN ([subquery])`. What's AC_DETAIL's primay key?

Comment: Primary Key is "NUM", but there "YEAR" and another field called "TIME_FRAME" are indexed.

Comment: I edited my answer with a different solution, I haven't tested it but you get the idea...

Comment: I think I am going to do a work-around of creating a table based on the query then doing a join on NUM to the AC_DETAIL table from the MT query. Not the most aesthetic way of doing it...